# Adding/Copying over 1,000 sheets within graph traversal

Tags: vba, excel, graph

Sorry if this is a little long.

I was asked to take a list of all company employees, create a hierarchical structure that relates employees and their managers, and then make an interface that takes a supervisor ID and outputs a new workbook with separate sheets for each employee beneath them (up to 3 levels) that contains information about the employee replacing the placeholders in a template summary.

I am currently successfully creating and populating a directed graph with nodes that have the employee ID as a key and Person objects as the data. 
The problem that I am having is when I try to expand on the traverse graph method in order to the separate employee summary sheets in a new workbook.

I wrote the code below to create the sheets, which can complete the task if there are only ~500 employees below the given supervisor – however, there are certain supervisors that can have up to 2,000 employees under them that are within the 3-level depth. With these supervisors, the program will run for around 10 minutes before completely freezing or crashing, and because I am printing to the immediate screen I can see that it seems to go to each employee/create each sheet at a slower and slower pace.

I know that it is something about the copying/adding of the worksheets that is doing this, because simply doing a Debug.Print of the de-queue-d node’s Person data within the traversal rather than adding a sheet will run in ~5 seconds total for any supervisor, regardless of if they have 200 or 2,000 employees beneath them.

I would like to know if there is a way to copy/add sheets that wouldn’t create that problem, but even more than that, it seems strange to me that I was asked to put all employees under the supervisor into the same workbook if there is going to be 2,000 sheets – it doesn’t seem like it would be feasible at all for the person using the program to then scroll through 1,000 odd sheets to find an employee they need to look at every time. So, I am also trying to figure out how to add a workbook for each parent node on a certain level and then have all of their children go into that specific workbook – I can’t figure out how to keep track of which workbook it would go into, because there is only separation of employees between levels.

Here is the code for the graph traversal:

```
Sub TraverseCreateSheets(rootS As String)

Dim wb As Workbook, newWb As Workbook
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
'the below sheet is the template sheet that I am copying to fill out
Dim managementSumTemplate As Worksheet
Set managementSumTemplate = wb.Sheets("Management Summary")


Dim maxDepth As Integer, curDepth As Integer
maxDepth = 3
curDepth = 0


Dim root As node
Set root = pNodeList.Item(rootS)
Dim visited As Object
Set visited = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

Dim queue As Object
Set queue = CreateObject("System.Collections.Queue")
queue.Enqueue root

Dim nullNode As node
Set nullNode = New node
nullNode.Key = "NULLNODE"
queue.Enqueue nullNode

Workbooks.Add
Set newWb = ActiveWorkbook

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False

'implementation of breadth first search using a queue
'because I had to be able to limit the levels correctly
Dim currentNode As node
Do While queue.Count <> 0
    Set currentNode = queue.Dequeue()

    If Not visited.Exists(currentNode.Key) Then


        If currentNode.Key = "NULLNODE" Then
            curDepth = curDepth + 1
            If curDepth > maxDepth Then
                Exit Do
            End If

            queue.Enqueue nullNode
            Dim peekNode As node
            Set peekNode = queue.Peek
            If peekNode.Key = "NULLNODE" Then
                Exit Do
            End If
        End If

        If Not currentNode.Key = "NULLNODE" Then
            visited.Add currentNode.Key, currentNode


            Dim curPer As Person
            Set curPer = currentNode.Data
            'just doing the below debug statement without any sheet additions can make entire traversal only take 5 seconds 
            Debug.Print "ID: " & currentNode.Key & " Name: " & curPer.Name & _
                " Location: " & curPer.Location & " PyrHead: " & curPer.PyrHead & _
                " Job: " & curPer.Job & " Job Entry: " & curPer.JobEntry & " Time in Pos: " & curPer.TimeInPos & _
                " Hire Date: " & curPer.HireDate & " Supervisor ID " & curPer.SupervisorID & " Supervisor " & curPer.Supervisor


            'adding the worksheet here, since I am copying the 
            'sheet I have to rename
            Dim reportSheet As Worksheet
            managementSumTemplate.Copy Before:=newWb.Sheets(1)
            Set reportSheet = newWb.Worksheets("Management Summary")
            reportSheet.Name = currentNode.Key

            reportSheet.Range("A7").Value = curPer.Location
            reportSheet.Range("A8").Value = curPer.PyrHead
            reportSheet.Range("B7").Value = curPer.Name
            reportSheet.Range("B8").Value = curPer.Job
            reportSheet.Range("B10").Value = curPer.HireDate
            reportSheet.Range("B11").Value = curPer.JobEntry
            reportSheet.Range("B12").Value = curPer.TimeInPos



            For Each neighbor In currentNode.Neighbors
                queue.Enqueue neighbor
            Next neighbor
        End If
    End If

Loop
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True

End Sub
```

Comment: The best thing to do is go to your boss and tell him that you have a better way.  Have one worksheet for the view and one for the model.  It would be better if you could just query an external workbook that you would use as a database.

Comment: Yeah, it seems like I'm going to have to convince people that this is the better option. Thanks.